# Python Selenium : Edge tab opening instead of Chrome

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
ChromeDriverManager().install()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("https://instagram.com/")
```

when running this script the Instagram tab is opening on Edge not on Chrome.

I Changed the default browser to Chrome but same issue

Comment: Did you restart the shell that executed the Python script after changing the default browser. Also, can you confirm that you can find the Google Chrome web driver via

```from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

webdriver_path = ChromeDriverManager().install()
print(webdriver_path)
```
```